# Find string in list of list

Tags: python, python-2.7

What is wrong with my search within a list of list? The output should be `It's there`

```
mylist = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']]
if 'a' in mylist:
    print "It's there"
else:
    print "it's not there"
```

Comment: `'a'` is **not** in `mylist`, it's in `mylist[0]`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe makes sense but how do I check in each index of mylist?

Comment: You could use `any`, or flatten to a single list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chain the nested lists and do as you normally would:

```
'a' in itertools.chain.from_iterable(mylist)
```

Alternatively, you can check each item in the list:

```
any('a' in item for item in mylist)
```

Comment: Interestingly (to me), this runs about 3 times faster than @inspectorG4dget's answer, according to `timeit` on Python 2.7. I think his has more potential for optimization, though, as `any()` isn't semantically required to operate sequentially whereas `itertools.chain` is.

Comment: itertools gets some speed increases because parts of it are implemented in C instead of running through python

Answer (score 2):

`'a'` is not in `mylist`; rather, it is in one of the lists contained within `mylist`:

```
In [240]: for sublist in mylist:
   .....:     if 'a' in sublist:
   .....:         print("'a' exists in", sublist)
   .....:         
'a' exists in ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

So, if you'd like to check if an element exists in **any** of many sub-lists:

```
In [241]: any('a' in sublist for sublist in mylist)
Out[241]: True
```

[[More on `any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any)]

Answer (score 0):

'a' is not in your list of course. Your list has two elements, each of which is a list. To look for 'a' within every list contained in your list, you need to flatten the lists into one list and search within that.